# Dual boot please help

Tags: dual-boot, photoshop

I have a hp envy m6 notebook.
running windows 8.1 genuine on my machine, i want to know how to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my machine as a dual boot?
please give me a proper guide.
and also tell me can i run adobe photoshop cc and lightroom 5.4 on ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop and lightroom are both closed source adobe products, and will not run directly under Ubuntu although they have released versions for both Mac and Windows.  They might run in Wine, and you can check compatibility [here](http://www.winehq.org/).